# Is there anyway to stop/close the javascript function?

Tags: javascript

there is javascript call function

```
myfunction();
```

I used

```
 $('#chap1').on('click', function(){
          audioplay(); 
    });
```

so the audio function run, I wonder something can "off/on" the function without calling a new function to stop the audio.

Is there any way to stop/close the javascript function?

Comment: I'm afraid your question lacks precision - can you elaborate please?

Comment: if I understand your question, this answer may apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330206/9533368

Comment: Only from within the function - it immediately ends when it reaches a `return` statement. Although this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) - what is the real issue you try to solve?

Comment: Please share your function codeblock. What are you trying to achieve? You may need to write a condition or use a method like setTimeout() within your function to determine when it ends.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I updated/edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by stop/close the function. If you mean to break out of the function, you can just use `return`. For example,

```
function myfunction() {
     if (condition) 
          return;
}
```

this will stop the function when the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

These posts may help with your logic:

[I am trying to make a simple toggle button in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047755/i-am-trying-to-make-a-simple-toggle-button-in-javascript)

[Toggle on/off buttons in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241473/toggle-on-off-buttons-in-javascript)

Save your state in a variable that's true or false, then specify opposing conditions in your function.

ie.

//start off not playing as the default state when page loads
var isPlaying = false;

```
 $('#chap1').on('click', function(){
if (isPlaying == false){
          audioplay(); 
}
if (isPlaying == true){
 !audioPlay();
    }
});
```

This above is pseudo-code. You may have to write a function to stop the playing because I can't see your `audioplay()` function.