# Open Close Camera with same button Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I have a problem. When I click the camera button (there is the code below) I can open the camera, but how can I turn the camera off when I click the same button.

A part of my code.

button :
`<a type="button" onclick="cameraOff()" name="button" id="button"> <i class="fas fa-video fa-2x cam-btn"></i> </a>`

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>

<script>
    function cameraOff() {

        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true
            }).then(function(stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The `cameraOff` function does not need to be a `async` function as you're never using await.

Comment: Also please never use an `<a>` when you mean to use `<button>`. `<a type="button"` is normally a mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off webcam/camera after using getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140147/turn-off-webcam-camera-after-using-getusermedia)

Answer (score 2):

Check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/video-onoff-js-zyrxh?file=/index.html

```
function cameraoff() {
        const stream = videoElem.srcObject;
        if (stream) {
          const tracks = stream.getTracks();

          tracks.forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
          });

          videoElem.srcObject = null;
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the
`video.srcObject = stream; video.play();`
with `video.srcObject={}; video.pause(); stream.stop();`
[reference to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28195344/10332261)

Comment: If you have already answered this elsewhere, why not flag the question as a duplicate?

Comment: That's good then, but why did you answer as well?

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried to answer his question while the process completes :) i even referenced the other answer but you are right should of just flagged it.

Comment: I looked at the page on the link but I think the camera is already on and there is a button to turn it off. Imagine being able to turn your camera on at one button and turn it off when you click it again.@evolutionxbox

Comment: @vikbaris [How to toggle on/off buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241473/toggle-on-off-buttons-in-javascript/37241526)